# How to update same redux state on two different components simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I have a React Native scenario in which I have two components, one is a `textInput` and the other is a `SVG` drawing. By filling out the `textInput` and pressing a button, the text is inserted as a data instance to an array stored in a redux state using a `dispatch` action (let's call it `textListState`).

```
//TEXT INPUT COMPONENT
//this code is just for presentation. it will cause errors obviously
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const submitHandler = (enteredText) => {
    dispatch(submitData(enteredText))
};

return(
    <TextInput ...... />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => submitHandler(enteredText) } />
)
```

Now, the `SVG` component updates all the features' fill color stored in the `textListState` using a function (e.g. `setFillColor`). This is done inside a `useEffect` hook with a dependency set to a prop (e.g. `propA`).

Now the problem is that I need to add `textListState` as a dependency to the `useEffect` because I want the newly entered text from the `textInput` to be included in the `SVG` component. But by doing so, I am creating an infinite loop, because the `setFillColor` also updates the `textListState`.

```
//SVG COMPONENT
const [textList, setTextList] = useState([]);
const textListState = useSelector(state => state.textListState);

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const setFillColor= useCallback((id, fill) => {
    dispatch(updateFillColor(id, fill))
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    //INFINITE LOOP BECAUSE textListState  KEEPS UPDATING WITH setFillColor
    const curTextList = [];

    for (const [i, v] of textListState.entries()) {
        setFillColor(5, "white")

        curTextList.push(
            <someSVGComponent />
        )
    }
    setTextList(curTextList);
}, [props.propA, textListState])

return(
    <G>
        {textList.map(x => x)}
    </G>
)
```

How can I achieve to be able to add the newly inserted text to the `SVG` component without creating an infinite loop?

---

### EDIT:

**The redux action**

```
export const UPDATE_TEXT = "UPDATE_TEXT";
export const SUBMIT_DATA = "SUBMIT_DATA";

export const updateFillColor = (id, fill) => {
    return { type: UPDATE_TEXT, id: id, fill: fill }
};

export const submitData= (text) => {
    return { type: SUBMIT_DATA, text: text }
};
```

**The redux reducer**

```
import { TEXT } from "../../data/texts";
import { UPDATE_TEXT } from "../actions/userActions";
import { INSERT_TEXT } from "../actions/userActions";

// Initial state when app launches
const initState = {
    textListState: TEXT
};

const textReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INSERT_TEXT :
            return {
                ...state,
                textListState: [
                    ...state.textListState,
                    action.text
                ]
            }
        case UPDATE_TEXT :
            const curText = state.textListState.filter(text => text.id === action.id)[0];

            return {
                ...state,
                textListState: [
                    ...state.textListState.slice(0, curIndex), //everything before current text
                    curText.fill = action.fill,
                    ...state.textListState.slice(curIndex + 1), //everything after current text
                ]
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default textReducer;
```

Comment: Can you add code for `updateFillColor` ?

Comment: I think you should go a bit more granular with redux state. textListState can be split as an object with text and color. Depend on text alone in useEffect and setFillColor should only update color.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Added the redux action and reducer

Comment: Unless there's more that you haven't shared, I don't see how `textListState` is a dependency in calling `setFillColor` in the effect.

Comment: @DrewReese I added the action and reducer. You can see that the `updateFillColor` function inside the `setFillColor` function updates the `textListState` in the reducer

Comment: You can't make a piece of state a dependency of an effect hook that ultimately updates *that* piece of state, that's what causes the infinite loop. If you want the newly added text to have a specific color, create an action that does that, or give new text a default fill, or keep the actions of adding a new text item and updating the fill color separated.

Comment: @DrewReese My code is more complex than what I shared. I wanted it to be more understandable. However, I added another part of it in the `SVG` component. You can see that inside the `useEffect` I am actually creating the sub-components when then are used in the `return` statement.

Comment: It isn't about component complexity, you just simply can't give a react hook a dependency of something it updates. It's just like calling `setState` in `componentDidUpdate` without doing any comparisons of previous and current state/prop values. The way you've explained it, what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of that. My question is not about "Why", but "How to prevent this for my use case". But I think @MohitSingh's solution using `textListState.length` is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to trigger useEffect only when new text is added then use `textListState.length` instead of `textListState` in dependency list.

If you want to do it both on update and insert (i.e. you want to fire even when text is updated in input) then use a boolean flag `textUpdated` in `textListState` and keep toggling it whenever there is a update or insert and use `textListState.textUpdated` in dependency list.